# Android tablet - modify OS so app launches on boot

Tags: android

I have written an Android application for a large store for the purposes of production inspection. I have a few Android tablets with the app installed on each that will be provided to the store.

As the only purpose of this tablet is to run a single app, is there a way to force this app to load upon switching on the tablet, and only allow this app to be used? The app does require an active 4G connection so it still needs to use a few of the core functions of Android as well as actually running the app.

I don't know much about this so apologies for naivety in advance, but could someone please shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need the permission in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Also, in yourAndroidManifest.xml, define your service and listen for the BOOT_COMPLETED action:

```
<service android:name=".MyService" android:label="My Service">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.myapp.MyService" />
</intent-filter>
</service>

<receiver
android:name=".receiver.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then you need to define the receiver that will get the BOOT_COMPLETED action and start your service.

```
public class StartMyActivityeAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Will this actually load the app or does it just run in the background?

Comment: It will start the activity `Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);`  whatever activity you provide try it and let me know if not working